# Single "S" and double "SS"

Tags: grammar

Does a single "s" in a word pronounced z? To be pronounced "s" should be a double s? (ss)

Comment: English has so many exceptions and conditional clauses that it's impossible to make a general statement on this.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. You need to include some examples and show some research you have done. Please make sure that you take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: You can consult a dictionary to learn the pronunciation of specific words. The general issue is fairly complicated, and is better suited to be explained by a chapter in a book than by a short answer here.

Comment: Also see: [When to pronounce ‹s› as /z/ in the middle of words?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/30195/when-to-pronounce-s-as-z-in-the-middle-of-words?rq=1), [Pronunciation of “chase”](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/58417/pronunciation-of-chase)

Answer (score 1):

You are right when it is -sion but not for -ssion

infusion collision incision (all sound like z)

but: permission, admission, fission (all sound like ssh)

while: permissive, incisive, effusive (all sound as ss)

That's just to give you an idea of what sumelic and Rhatony and Joe L are trying to explain to you.